# After call of another control, I need to set the focus to the calling control

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, focus, sender

From a ImageButton I call a panel for showing the pic large. After closing the panel I need to set the focus to the calling ImageButton.

The website runs on an public iis-server. The panel uses the whole display.

```vb
 Protected Sub ImageButton1_Click(sender As Object, e As ImageClickEventArgs) Handles IBTV80NDB20001C.Click, IBTV80NDB20001A.Click …...

        MainImage.ImageUrl = sender.ImageUrl

        PanelImage.Visible = True    
        PanelClose.Visible = True       'a close-button
End Sub

 Protected Sub IBTClose_Click(sender As Object, e As ImageClickEventArgs) Handles IBTClose.Click, MainImage.Click
        MainImage.ImageUrl = ""
        PanelImage.Visible = False
        PanelClose.Visible = False

        '???.Focus()

    End Sub
```

How can I store the sender temporarily?
Or how can I take a string, extracted from the ImageURL, for setting the focus to th ImageButton?

Comment: Try `CType(sender, Control).Focus()`

Comment: From MS Docs "Focus is a low-level method intended primarily for custom control authors." Use `.Select`. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.focus?view=netframework-4.8

Comment: I fear, your answers are not helpful for my problem. Setting focus to a known control is quote easy. But I don´t know the control, I have only the id of it as string.
But thanks anyway for your effort.